# Spacing between groups of bars in histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2

When I produce histograms in ggplot2 where the bar positions are `dodge`, I expect something like this where there is space between the groups of bars (i.e. notice the white space between each groups of red/green pairs):

[image]

I'm having a hard time producing the same effect when I build a histogram with continuous data. I can't seem to add space between the groups of bars, and instead, everything gets squashed together. As you can see, it makes it visually difficult to compare the red/green pairs:

[image]

To reproduce my problem, I created a sample data set here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/i9nxzo1cmbwwfsa/data.csv?dl=0

Code to reproduce:

```
data <- read.csv("https://www.dropbox.com/s/i9nxzo1cmbwwfsa/data.csv?dl=1")

ggplot(data, aes(x = soldPrice, fill = month)) +
    geom_histogram(binwidth=1e5, position=position_dodge()) +
    labs(x="Sold Price", y="Sales", fill="") +
    scale_x_continuous(labels=scales::comma, breaks=seq(0, 2e6, by = 1e5)) +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5))
```

How can I add white space between the groups of red/green pairs?

Comment: I added an alternative without overlapping bars. Please, have a look.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Alternative 1: overlapping bars with `geom_histogram()`

From `?position_dodge()`:

*`Dodging preserves the vertical position of an geom while adjusting the horizontal position`*

This function accepts a `width` argument that determines the space to be created.

To get what I think you want, you need to supply a suitable value to `position_dodge()`. In your case, where `binwidth=1e5`, you might play with e.g. 20% of that value: **`position=position_dodge(1e5-20*(1e3))`**.
(I left the rest of your code untouched.)

You could use the following code:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = soldPrice, fill = month)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth=1e5, position=position_dodge(1e5-20*(1e3))) + ### <-----
  labs(x="Sold Price", y="Sales", fill="") +
  scale_x_continuous(labels=scales::comma, breaks=seq(0, 2e6, by = 1e5)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5))
```

yielding this plot:

[image]

## Alternative 2: use ggplot-object and render with `geom_bar`

`geom_histogram()` was not designed to produce what you want. `geom_bar()` on the other hand provides the flexibility you need.

You can generate the histogram with `geom_histogram` and save it in an ggplot-object. Then, you generate the plotting information with `ggplot_build()`. Now,
you may use the histogram plotting information in the object to generate a bar plot with `geom_bar()`

```
## save ggplot object to h
h <- ggplot(data, aes(x = soldPrice, fill = month)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth=1e5, position=position_dodge(1e5-20*(1e3)))

## get plotting information as data.frame
h_plotdata <- ggplot_build(h)$data[[1]]
h_plotdata$group <- as.factor(h_plotdata$group)
levels(h_plotdata$group) <- c("May 2018", "May 2019")

## plot with geom_bar
ggplot(h_plotdata, aes(x=x, y=y, fill = group)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  labs(x="Sold Price", y="Sales", fill="") +
  scale_x_continuous(labels=scales::comma, breaks=seq(0, 2e6, by = 1e5)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5))
```

yielding this graph:

[image]

Please, let me know whether this is what you want.

Comment: It's getting close, but now the bars are overlapping. If you look at my first screenshot, you'll see the groups of bars are side-by-side with no overlap, then there's white space between the groups. I tried `position_dodge2` (with different `padding` values) and it adds white space, but it doesn't group the related bars together.

Comment: Thanks for Alternative 2. That's some impressive stuff! I don't know how you did it, but it works perfectly. I'll have to learn more about `ggplot_build`. :-)

Comment: Glad I could help. I had to look it up too, and I learned some in the meantime ;-)